# Automapper two level mapping

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper, automapping

I have a problem with my AutoMapper configuration, I can map for one level but I don't know if there exists a way to map for two levels

I have:

```
Class A 
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string nom {get; set;}
    public B Bprop {get; set;}
}

Class B
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string nom {get; set;}
    public C Cprop {get; set;}
}

Class C 
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string nom {get; set;}
}
```

My code for configuration is below, and it works if I delete `Cprop` from `class B`:

```
 MapperTools<DatabaseA, A> mapperToolsService =
     new MapperTools<DatabaseA, A>(MappingHelper);

 mapperToolsService.MappingConfig.Configuration.CreateMap<DatabaseA, A>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Bprop , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DatabaseB));

 mapperToolsService.MappingConfig.Configuration.CreateMap<DatabaseB,B>();
```

Please, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is three level mapping.

Add mapping for class C as you have for class B.
Extend mapping for class B to cover Cprop.

Assuming that DatabaseX have Xprop field corresponding to Xprop field in target classes(A, B, C) it should look like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DatabaseA, A>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Bprop , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bprop));

Mapper.CreateMap<DatabaseB,B>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Cprop , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Cprop));

Mapper.CreateMap<DatabaseC, C>();
```

Here is working example: https://github.com/st4hoo/Automapper3LevelMappingExample